# Adding Temporary Data to List and bind it to a DataGridView Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, generic-list, temporary

I want to put temporary datas into a generic list and bind it to the datagridview.
However, I can only put 1 row in the datagridview, I want to input multiple rows just like a database.

Here's what I've tried, please tell me how to fix it. thanks :))

```
MyClass
{
   private List<object> _list = new List<object>();;

   public MyClass()
   {
   }

   protected void OnClickButton(object sender, args e)
   {
     _list.Add(new { Name = textBoxName.Text, Gender = genderComboBox.Text });
     dataGridView1.DataSource = _list;
   }
}
```

Thank you very much! I'm really STUCK-overflow with this problem.

Comment: Well, you only added 1 item to the list - have you tried adding another one?

Comment: @alex I can only add once. If I click the button again nothing happens, :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `BindingList<object>` instead of `List<object>`, e.g. :

```
BindingList<object> bList = new BindingList<object>();

public MyClass()
{
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bList.Add(new { Name = "Foo", Gender = "Bar" });
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bList;
}
```

The problem with your code is that you're adding an element to `_list` and then you pass the list as datasource of the grid. 
The first time everything works fine. The next times it doesn't work because  `DataGridView.DataSource` property internally performs a check that verify if the passed object is equal (or better reference-equal) to the current, and in case it does nothing.

`BindingList<T>` works, because it exposes events (used internally by the grid) reporting when the list is modified, so basically you could also avoid to pass it to the `DataSource` every time except the first one.

---

As a side note, I suggest you to use a specific class (as shown in [@Alex answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9341481/316644)) instead of put an anonymous-class in a list of `object`.

For example using a custom class like `Person`, you can pass an empty `BindingList<Person>` to `grid.DataSource` then add other `Person` objects without any problems.

Instead, you can't pass an empty `BindingList<object>` to `grid.DataSource` because it results in a no-columns grid and so after you cannot add any elements having public properties (because the public properties are turned into columns). Thus, you need to pass a `BindingList<object>` with at least one object defined, such that the grid can understand what the columns will be and create them.

Comment: Thank You Very Much Mr. For explaining and answering my question. :))

Comment: @rjtubera: You're welcome. I've just added one little explanation about why a custom class is preferable to an anonymous-class, if you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that DataGridView always needs to be reset if you use a it your way.

```
public class Person
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Gender { get; set; }
}

// Your control
private List<Person> _persons = new List<Person>();

// Click Event
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
_persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Test", Gender = "Male" });
dataGridView1.DataSource = _persons;
```

This refreshes the datagridview with the current data in your List

Using a `BindingList<T>` seems to be the appropriate way though. (Thanks to @digEmAll )

```
private BindingList<Person> _persons = new BindingList<Person>();

// Load Event
dataGridView1.DataSource = _persons;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Test", Gender = "Male" });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of list